# How can I get the current apt command called in a DPkg::Pre-Invoke script?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I understand I can use `DPkg::Pre-Invoke` to run a script/command before `apt` does it's thing.

```
DPkg::Pre-Invoke { "/tmp/pre-invoke.sh"; };
```

In my script, I want to get the full `apt` command that was executed. For example, if I run `apt install funky` then, inside my script, I want to be able to see the calling command was `apt install funky`, or `install funky`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the environment in the script to see what's available?

Comment: Yeah. No dice. There is a `SUDO_CMD` but that is only there if the command is invoked through `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get the information I am after but I don't like it -- it is too hacky. I feel like there is a better way. I am only sharing this in case nobody else can tell me a better way.

Essentially I walk up the current processes process tree until I find the one whose command is `apt`.

```
# we need to work up the process tree to find the apt command that triggered the call to this script
# get the initial PPID
PARENT_PID=${PPID}
# trim leading spacess
PARENT_PID="${PARENT_PID## }"

# if the command for this PPID is not apt
while [ "$(ps -ho comm "${PARENT_PID}")" != "apt" ] ; do
    # go up one level
    PARENT_PID=$(ps -ho ppid "${PARENT_PID}")
    PARENT_PID="${PARENT_PID## }"
done

APT_CMD="$(ps -ho args "${PARENT_PID}")"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem "hacky" to me.  apt doesn't provide the information you need, so you're using appropriate tools with a reasonable algorithm to get that info.   IMO, it would only qualify as hacky if apt did provide the info but you chose to DIY it.